# How do I programmatically add a file to a Solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vsx, vspackage

I am developing a VS Package and part of the functionality that I need to implement is to add a file to the Solution Items of the currently open Solution.

This is exactly the same action that would be performed manually if you right-click on a Solution and choose Add > Existing Item.  Then selected a file on disk.

I have taken a good look at the DTE and DTE2 interfaces and can see the operations to add and manipulate projects but there doesn't appear to be any operations for adding individual files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok,  I realised I could just record a Macro to capture the operation then examine the code in the VS Macro IDE.

The code required to do this is.

```
DTE.ItemOperations.AddExistingItem(filePath);
```

Comment: How does one actually deliver the file in the vstemplate? Is it possible?

Comment: @tofutim I'm not sure exactly what your comment is asking.  This question doesn't have anything to do with VS Templates.  Perhaps you need to start your own specific question?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to access the [ProjectItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) member of the Project and call `AddFromFile()`

```
ProjectItem pi = project.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to add the item to the Solution and not to a specific project

Comment: Solution has [AddFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solution_members%28v=vs.90%29) too

Comment: No that call doesn't work. It expects a Project to be provided at the path you give. I've just figured it out. See my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `AddFromFile` to the `ProjectItems` collection of a `Project`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile(v=vs.100).aspx

edit:

To Add to a Solution, `AddFromFile` against the `Solution`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to add the item to the Solution and not to a specific project

Comment: Then call `AddFromFile` against the `Solution`

Comment: No that call doesn't work.  It expects a Project to be provided at the path you give.  I've just figured it out.  See me answer above.