# Add image to project resources folder runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a method to save an uploaded image to my project resources folder. The image is correctly added to my resources folder, but I can't use the image because I can't set the build action. Where can I store uploaded images, which folder? I read about the bin directory but is this good practice?

Resources is a folder under my project. As you can see in the screenshot below I can't set the build action of my uploaded image (beats_1.jpg).

[image]

Code to save the image

```
var path = string.Format(@"{0}\Resources\Images\{1}", Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName, GiftImageFileName);
var resizedImage = GiftImage.CreateResizedImage(100, 100, 0);
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(resizedImage));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so i'm guessing that you want to perform this process BEFORE you build, and therefore your file is included in the compiled output as a resource and you can reference it in the compiled executable.

There are two approaches to this, one is the quick and dirty, one is more complex and correct.

Quick and dirty: (This should be performed when the Visual Studio Solution is not loaded)

- Open the Project CSPROJ file via an XML modification library in your C# code (e.g. using XDoc).
- Programmatically add the following under the `<Project>` section

  ```
   <ItemGroup>
      <Resource Include="Resources\Images\beats_1.png" />
      <Resource Include="Resources\Images\beats_2.png" />
      <Resource Include="Resources\Images\beats_n.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
  ```

  - Save the CSPROJ file
  - Compile your project

More complex and correct:
 - Use a VSPackage visual studio add-in to modify the current loaded project and add new resource items.
 - See here: [How do I programmatically add a file to a Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933855/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-file-to-a-solution)

Comment: How do I access the projectitems from my converter in WPF?